# A lan pet Project

Tags: c#, flash, lan

Its an idea i have had for many years and i want to finally start doing it.I am still a newbie , but i have enough experience to understand new things.
The basic idea is this.There will be an animal.A spider for example, which can run across systems connected in lan.It comes and sits in one computer, and if the user nudges it it crawls away to visit  a nearby or random computer, where it stays until nudged again.That's it.
Now i want to know the following things
1)Which languages are  best for this one?I have some knowledge of C# and java.I can do flash animations also
2)What all should i search for to get started?
 
Its a nonsense project and has no use to anybody.But i will get immense pleasure if i see it work.I will be posting more questions as i progress.

Comment: I would love if the spider could become sad when everyone nudge it away, until someone let it stay for a while and it become happy again :)

Comment: The idea is very interesting, but what if the spider caught a virus and it could then be used as a host to infect other computers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be too difficult in C#.  You could create a program (or service) that runs on the systems across the lan, and use [WCF Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx) to find other copies of the program running on other systems.

When you want to make the spider move, just see which other systems are available, and send a message to that system that you want it to go there.  You'd then make your spider crawl away, and on that system, crawl into place.

Comment: Thanks Reed.I'll keep updating